# How to consume a REST api that needs username/password authentication in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-restivus

I want to consume a REST api that needs a username/password authentication in node.js. The code that consumes the api is as follows:

```js
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login/'

request.get(url,{'auth': {'user': 'test35','pass': 'mypassword','sendImmediately': false}},function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('post failed:', err);
  }

  console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

With the above code, the error I get is:

```js
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "API endpoint does not exist"
}
```

The api is written in meteor restivus and you can see it in the following question's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287691/first-logging-in-is-not-required-when-using-meteor-restivus)

In the API, when I remove the api's authRequired: true, i.e, remove

```js
{
        routeOptions: {
            authRequired: true
        }
  }
```

and in the code that consumes the API **above**, change url from

> 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login/

to:

> http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles/

and run "node accessRESTapi.js", I am able to consume the REST api! What I am not able to do correctly is the authentication when "authRequired: true" is set as per above! Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Updated based on info from comments

The style of request is quite different between logging in to get a token and the subsequent requests:

### For login

The [docs](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#logging-in) specify that login actions must be done with a `POST` request to `/api/login/` with a body that contains `username` or `email` and `password` as url-encoded params

```js
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login/'
var user = 'test35';
var pass = 'mypassword';

// Save these for future requests
var userId;
var authToken;

// Use POST instead of GET
request.post(
  {
    uri: url,
    // I'm using form because it matches the urlEncoding behaviour expected by `restivus`
    form: { username: user, password: pass }
  },
  function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('post failed:', err);
    }
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    authToken = json.data.authToken;
    userId = json.data.userId;
    console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  }
);
```

### For future requests

Now you need to set the correct headers with the previously saved `userId` and `authToken`

[According to the docs](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#authenticated-calls), that means `X-User-Id` and `X-Auth-Token` headers on all subsequent requests

```js
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles/'

request.get({
  uri: url, 
  headers: {
    'X-User-Id': userId,
    'X-Auth-Token': authToken
  }
}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('get failed:', err);
  }

  console.log('Get successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

---

### Putting it together:

We want to make sure we get the `authToken` before making any further requests.

This means making the second request in the callback of the first function like so:

```js
var request = require('request');

var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login/';
var user = 'test35';
var pass = 'mypassword';

// Save these for future requests
var userId;
var authToken;

// Use POST instead of GET
request.post(
  {
    uri: url,
    // I'm using form because it matches the urlEncoding behaviour expected by `restivus`
    form: { username: user, password: pass }
  },
  function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('post failed:', err);
    }
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    authToken = json.data.authToken;
    userId = json.data.userId;
    console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);

    // And now we make the second request
    // Welcome to callback hell
    var articlesUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles/';

    request.get({
      uri: articlesUrl, 
      headers: {
        'X-User-Id': userId,
        'X-Auth-Token': authToken
      }
    }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('post failed:', err);
      }

      console.log('Get successful!  Server responded with:', body);
    });
  }
);
```